# ExternalAssets with authentication

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

In my case I would like to check if user is set in session and if set the ExternalAssets would be loaded. If user is not set, it should redirect to login page. So my question, how I convert object Action to result? My actual code look like this.

```
public class CustomAssetsController extends AuthenticationController {

    public static Action<AnyContent> index() {

        if(account == null)
            return redirect("/");

        return ExternalAssets.at("/Users/abuder/projects/remoteservice/central","index.html");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use action composition.
Please refer [Play action composition](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaActionsComposition)

Using this you can even implement your authentication and authorization module in best way.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently a limitation in Play *Java*

The following is from [jroper](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3004):

> This is a current limitation of intercepting requests in Java - the
>   method is only used to decorate Java actions, but the assets
>   controller is a Scala action and so can't be decorated with a Java
>   action because the Java API sits on top of the Scala API, not the
>   other way around.
>
> Whether we can make this work, I'm not sure. If you do want to
>   intercept requests to the assets controllers, then you'll have to
>   implement a Scala filter:
>
> http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaHttpFilters
>
> Then you can use this in the Java Global object by returning it from
>   the filters method.